# pancake sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm having a bit of trouble with my assignment; I was given a task of coming up with my own solution to the pancake problem.

I've gotten most of my code down, except for this one part (following is in pseudocode):

```
//assuming input is an array of [0...n-1] size
int maxValue = -infinity
for int i <- 0 to n-1 do
{
    for int j <-i to n-1 do
    {
       if A[j] > maxValue
       {
          maxValue <- A[j]
          maxPos <- j
    if ((maxPos == n-1) && (maxPos > i))
    {
        flip(i) //flipping starting from index i
    }
    /*the following is the bit i'm stuck on
    i know that should be able to flip the max value IN the array 
    (but not the end) to the n-1 term. 
    On the next iteration of the loop, i flip the maxValue (now held in the last 
    element) into the slot that is either at the beginning of the array, or at the
    element closest to the elements already sorted */
    maxValue <- -infinity
```

And sorry, for the random short code, i pressed sumbit too early on when i was typing =(.

Comment: what is maxValue? and what is the value of n?

Comment: N is the number of items in the array. MaxValue is the max value in the array for that particular iteration

Answer (score 1):

Pancake sort:

Pancake sorting is the colloquial term for the mathematical problem of sorting a disordered stack of pancakes in order of size when a spatula can be inserted at any point in the stack and used to flip all pancakes above it.

A pancake number is the maximum number of flips required for a given number of pancakes.

***flip(array, i): Reverse array from 0 to i.***

**Pseudo code Pancake sort:**

**1) iMax = Index of Largest element in unsorted array.**

Find index of the maximum element index in arr[0..unsorted_array_size -1].

**2) Call flip(array, iMax)**

It will flip all element of array from 0 to iMax index.
The largest element will be the first element in the array.

**3) Call flip(array, unsorted_array_size -1)**

Flip complete unsorted array which result to put the largest element at the end of the unsorted array.

Complexity :
Total O(n) flip operations are performed in where each flip will take O(n) time. Therefore complexity is O(n^2).

http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2015/11/pancake-sort-in-java.html

Comment: I believe the pancake number is actually the *minimum* number of flips, not the maximum.  The referenced link is incorrect as well.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting

Answer (score 0):

I think you are stuck with `infinity`. You can just take it as a `large integer or long number`.